# the sum of all possible values of natural number 30 < Q < 48

Tags: probability

I don't understand this problem very well. It says "If...., then it must..." Let's say, P=15, then it can't be divided by Q larger than 15. I assume Q should be 3, 5, 15, 2, 4, 7, 12, 28.

> If a natural number> P is divisible by 15 and 28, then it must also be divisible by the natural number Q where 30 < Q < 48. Find the sum of all possible values of Q satisfying this condition.

Comment: Hint:  $15=3\times 5$ and $28=2^2\times 7$ so if a number is divisible by both then it must be divisible by $2^2\times 3\times 5\times 7$, or any factor of that.

Comment: If a number is divisible by $15$ and $28$, it must be divisible by $(15)(28)$, since $15$ and $28$ are relatively prime. So we are being asked in effect to find all numbers $Q$ strictly between $30$ and $48$ such that $Q$ divides $420$. Go through the list, $31$ no, $32$ no, $33$ no, $34$ no, $35$ yes, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

We are told that $P$ must be divisible by both 15 and 28 so one such number is $ 15 \times 28 = 420 $ but this may not be the smallest number that is divisible by both these numbers.  We need to find the lowest common multiple of both 15 and 28.

One way to do this would be to write out the 28 times table checking each one until we find one that is divisible by 15.  A better way however is to find the prime factors of both 15 and 28.

$ 15 = 3 \times 5 $ and $ 28 = 2^2 \times 7 $

The lowest common multiple is thus: $ 2^2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 420 $
because our initial two numbers are relatively prime but we didn't know this initially.

The next step from here is to find all numbers $Q$ such that $30 < Q < 48$ and $\frac{420}{Q}$ is an integer. You can do this either by trying them all or considering which ones have 2, 3, 5 or 7 as a factor.

Make sure you don't use any number $Q$ more than once and add them all up.

I'll leave the rest as an exercise

Comment: It sounds like the OP couldn't parse the question itself, rather than being unsure about how to deal with least common multiples.

Comment: @anomaly you may be correct that the issue is more an issue of understanding what is being asked rather than being able to understand lowest common multiples or highest common factors.  I hope this has helped the OP understand what has been asked of them.